# How to To Loop through cells in a column, and to find the latest date of the list in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-automation

Actual work to loop through the **Column A** which has same value of with certain range, with that range have to check the latest date with the comment in **Column B** and print the comment with date in **Column C** kindly help me to find the solution for this problem.. Or Guide to find the solution for this problem... Kindly check the Screenshot for clear information.. Thanks in Advance Experts

[image]

Comment: Please provide any code you have tried thusfar. StackOverflow is here to collaborate, not code-for-you. If you have not tried any code thusfar, please try the Macro Recorder on the Developer tab. If you are just looking for tips, look into Application.Max() for the most recent date (Assumes formatting correctly).

Comment: @Cyril Let me post the code now.. But my problem how to get the Application.Max() in a certain Range..

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend declaring some dimensions in a fairly simple approach (assumes you have sorted Column A):

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, LR As Long
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LR
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i - 1).Value Then
        If j = 0 Then
           j = Cells(i - 1, 1).Row
        End If
    Else
        If j > 0 Then
            k = Cells(i - 1, 1).Row
            Cells(j, 3).Value = Application.Max(Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(k, 1)))
            j = Cells(i, 1).Row
            k = 0
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Not particularly a fan of coding for someone that hasn't put in the code and shown some additional effort, but given the comment about how to use multiple ranges within the loop, you really need to show the code to have it make sense.

Comment: Actually Bro... I've taken both columns in to loops and compared the values to get the latest date..I got little bit confused in that .. so that only i've posted like this..

Comment: @BharathBabu If you can, try posting up those loops; though, I feel like this posted code should get you to where you need want to be.  Per your comment on the post itself, you mentioned just having issues with using the Max() with smaller, more specific ranges, so that is what I have posted.

Comment: @Cyril `LR` should be `Long` not `String`! Why do you declare `j` and `k` as string and then don't use it at all but you don't declare `a` and `b`? **Always use `Option Explicit`**

Comment: @Peh Was thinking a and b, and my goto is always i, j, k when typing; I copied from another sub and that's my bad.  Updated to show appropriately.

Comment: @Cyril Eehm but `j` and `k` should be `Long` too. I hope you are familiar about the difference between `Long` and `String`. String counters don't make much sense.

Comment: @Peh I am familiar and only noted that LR was to be updated, rather than looking through and being more thorough in updating the rest.  My apologies.  I will say that i've been a lot better about using Long over Integer since you posted on something I did a few weeks back.